# Despite creating Workflows, Logic App Workflow listing is empty

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I created a Workflow in Logic App, but the workflow listing in my Logic App keeps showing empty most of the times (though some times it does show my created workflows).

I've tried force-refreshing the page multiple times. Didn't work.

When I tried to open the workflow in Designer using its URL from browser history, it showed me an "unexpected error":

[image: "Unexpected error" loading workflow]

Switched from Firefox to Edge: didn't make any difference.

The overview of the workflow:

[image: Workflow overview]

Yet the list of workflows is empty:

[image: Empty workflow list]

There are a bunch of messages in the activity log of the Logic App that I'm unsure what to make of:

[image]

I'm brand new to Logic Apps, so can't figure out what's going on.